# Can or Is any data written to an internal hard drive when booting from an external drive (2019 Mac Pro w/ external m.2 NVME)

Tags: ssd

Is any data written to an internal hard drive when booting and using an external drive (

Using a 2019 Mac Pro and a external m.2 NVME in an enclosure.

Does or can any data (temp files, file remnants from RAM?) be written to the fixed internal drive DESPITE booting and using an external drive?

I assume not, looking to COMPLETELY By pass the internal drive and seeing if it is possible on an apple Mac pro where the internal drive is soldered/fixed.

Comment: Yes, it will see & be able to use/launch apps on the internal. It will also Spotlight index it, unless you prevent it from mounting using `fstab` - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205814/time-machine-restore-to-new-partition-different-computer